# Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1\neq 0$. Prove that if every proper ideal of $R$ is prime, then $R$ is a field.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm stuck on a detail in the proof of the following:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1\neq 0$. Prove that if every proper ideal of $R$ is prime, then $R$ is a field.

Since $0 \neq 1$ we have that $\{0 \}$ is a proper ideal of $R$.  Further, $R$ is an integral domain since if $a\cdot b \in \{0\}$, then either $a=0$ or $b=0$ as $\{0\}$ is prime.  Now I would like to prove that $\{0\}$ is the only proper ideal of $R$ which would imply that $\{0\}$ is maximal and $F/\{0\} \cong F$ is a field.  My idea is that if $A,B \subseteq R$ are two proper ideals then it must be that $A = B$, and therefore any proper ideal of $R$ is $\{0\}$.  Notice that $AB \subseteq B$ so that $AB$ is also a proper ideal of $R$.  Since $AB \subseteq AB$, and $AB$ is prime, we have that either $A \subseteq AB \subseteq A$ or $B \subseteq AB \subseteq B$, which implies that either that $B = AB \subseteq A$ or $A = AB \subseteq B$.  Say $B = AB \subseteq A$.  I'm now stuck trying to show that $A \subseteq B$.

Is there a better way to do this?  I have also tried picking $r \in R\setminus\{0\}$, and showing that $r^{-1} \in R$ without success.

Comment: Found the duplicate by searching "every proper ideal is prime." Good to try next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Take $A = B$

> Take $A = B = (a)$ a principal ideal. Then $(a^2)=(a)$ implies that $a^2$ divides $a$, which in an integral domain can only happen if $a=0$ or $a$ is invertible.